# Why Input hidden when set a lot data

Tags: html, css

I tried to know what's that problem 1 week ago but I can't found solution never so I succumbed to the problem

the problem is when put a lot data the input is gone check images below

*short data*
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6R1C.png)

*long data*
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IorZI.png)

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .con-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="con-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="for test">
    <div class="a">
      <span>test test test test test</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: input is not hidden, i think height creates problem here because you set 100vh

Comment: any working example to solve your problem ?

Comment: @NishargShah Do you can fix it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solve your problem

```css
.container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    top:50%;
    position:absolute;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="con-1">
        <input type="text" placeholder="for test">
        <div class="a">
            <span>test test test test testtest test test test testtest test test test testtest test test test testtest test test test testtest test test test testtest test test test testtest test test test test</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have updated the code, with top:50% and position:absolute, now it will work